# Scrapy - how to wait for json page to be fully loaded

Tags: python, json, parsing, scrapy

I scrape json pages but sometimes I get this error:

```
ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://reqbin.com/echo/get/json/page/2>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 857, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback( # type: ignore[misc]
  File "/home/user/path/scraping.py", line 239, in parse_images
    jsonresponse = json.loads(response.text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/init.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 48662 (char 48661)
```

So I suspect that the json page does not have the time to be fully loaded and that's why parsing of its json content fails. And if I do it manually, I mean taking the json content as a string and loading it with the json module, it works and I don't get the `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` error.

What I've done so far is to set in `settings.py`:

```
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5

DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 600

DOWNLOAD_FAIL_ON_DATALOSS = False

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 8
```

hoping that it would slow down the scraping and solve my problem but the problem still occurs.

Any idea on how to be sure that the json page loaded completely so the parsing of its content does not fail ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to increase DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT. It usually helps. If that's not enough, you can try to reduce CONCURRENT_REQUESTS.

If that still doesn't help, try use retry request. You can write your own `retry_request` function and call it `return self.retry_request(response)`.
Or do it something like that `req = response.request.copy(); req.dont_filter=True` And `return req`.

You can also use RetryMiddleware. Read more on the documentation page https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry